# Условие авторизации в приложении на Flask

Tags: html, python, flask

У меня есть функция по авторизации пользователя в моём приложении на Flask

Как прописать подобное условие:

```
if password == "password" and login == "login":
    #Успешно авторизовывайся
else:
    #Сообщить о неверном логине или пароле
```

Вот сама функция без условия:

```
def login():
form = LoginForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    flash('Login requested for user {}, remember_me={}'.format(
        form.username.data, form.remember_me.data))


    return redirect('/index')
return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

Как к ней добавить подобное условие?

Вот код странички:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container-fluid" id = "Lol">
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                Войдите в свой аккаунт!
        </div>
</div>


<div class = "container-fluid col-md-3" > 
        <h1>Войти</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <p>
                {{ form.username.label }}<br>
                {{ form.username(size=50) }}<br>
                {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{ form.password.label }}<br>
                {{ form.password(size=50) }}<br>
                {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </p>
            <p>{{ form.remember_me() }} {{ form.remember_me.label }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

P.S в Base.html код навигационной панели и импорт Bootstrap